# Kruskal's algorithm - Find the tree with the least possible weight

Tags: graph-theory

I need to find the tree with the least possible weight with Kruskal's algorithm.
[image: Graph]

Here is my attempt: B-E-F-A-D and then I get stuck.

Is my attempt looking correct? How should I continue?

Comment: We take *edges* with the least weight, that don't form a cycle. So you begin with $2$

Comment: ...which I have done

Comment: The edges are not necessary consecutive. One may take $be$, then $hi$, then $ad$, ans so on

Comment: Oh, I see...
How about this one:

BE, BG, GH, HI, EF, BD, DA, AK, KC

[Attempt at solution](http://i.gyazo.com/890c2d932e9053ab4f25ff1c45325659.png)

Comment: There's a helpful animation here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm on the right. The edges taken don't need to be connected, except the last step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must start with $be$, since it’s the unique edge with least weight. At each step you must choose an edge of minimum possible weight that does not complete a cycle, so your next edge can be any of the edges of weight $3$: $ad$, $ef$, or $hi$. (Note that there is no requirement that your set of edges form a tree at this stage.) No matter which one you pick, your third edge must be one of the other two, and your fourth edge must be the remaining one, so after $4$ steps you must have the edges $be$, $ad$, $ef$, and $hi$, and they form a forest of $3$ trees.

Your next edge will be one of the edges of weight $4$: $ak$, $bd$, or $bg$. You can add any of them without completing a cycle, so your fifth edge can be any one of them. It then turns out that you can add the other two in either order without completing a cycle, so after $7$ steps you’ll have the edges $be$, $ad$, $ef$, $hi$, $ak$, $bd$, and $bg$. Now your forest has two trees, one with the edge $hi$, and the other with the other six edges chosen so far.

See if you can finish it on your own from here; I’ve put the rest of the construction in the spoiler-protected block below. (Mouse-over to see it.)

> The next lightest edge is $de$, but it completes a cycle with $be$ and $bd$, so you can’t use it. The next ones up after that are $ck$ and $gh$, both of weight $6$; neither completes a cycle with the $7$ edges already chosen, so you can choose either of them next. When you’ve done that, you’ll find that you can choose the other as well, so that after nine steps you have the edges $be$, $ad$, $ef$, $hi$, $ak$, $bd$, $bg$, $ck$, and $gh$. Since the graph has $10$ vertices, you know that any spanning tree must have $10-1=9$ edges, so at this point you must be done.